# Scraping a Nested Data and Insert them into a Single Array

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I have the following HTML Structure:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      <h3>TheFirst</h3>
    </div>
    <div class='LastDiv'>TheLast</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <h3>TheSecond</h3>
    </div>
    <div class='LastDiv'>TheLast</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <h3>TheNew</h3>
    </div>
    <div class='LastDiv'>TheLastNew</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What I'm trying to do here is to extract from this structure the following Data:

```
{
  'TheLast': ['TheFirst', 'TheSecond'],
  'TheLastNew': ['TheNew']
}
```

What I do is the following:

```
data = {}
list = response.css('ul li').extract()
for li in list:
    data[li.css('div.LastDiv::text')].append(li.css('div > h3::text'))
print(data)
```

But I keep getting this Error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'css'

Is there a faster way to extract these data in such a set?

**list** values =

```
['<li>\r\n    <div>\r\n      <h3>TheFirst</h3>\r\n    </div>\r\n    <div class="LastDiv">TheLast</div>\r\n  </li>', '<li>\r\n    <div>\r\n      <h3>TheSecond</h3>\r\n    </div>\r\n    <div class="LastDiv">TheLast</div>\r\n  </li>', '<li>\r\n    <div>\r\n      <h3>TheNew</h3>\r\n    </div>\r\n    <div class="LastDiv">TheLastNew</div>\r\n  </li>']
```

overall result before `print()` is

```
>>> data = {}
>>> list = response.css('ul li').extract()
>>> for li in list:
...  data[li.css('div.LastDiv::text')].append(li.css('div > h3::text'))
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'css'
```

Comment: Does the error occur in the line with `response.css` or `li.css`?

Comment: Can you add the error stack trace? Can you also paste the results of `list`

Comment: @MithunArunan the result is the `li` parts like this `<li>
    <div>
      <h3>TheFirst</h3>
    </div>
    <div class='LastDiv'>TheLast</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <h3>TheSecond</h3>
    </div>
    <div class='LastDiv'>TheLast</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <h3>TheNew</h3>
    </div>
    <div class='LastDiv'>TheLastNew</div>
  </li>`

Comment: @meisterluk it occurs on the part of `data[li.css('div.LastDiv::text)].append(li.css('div > h3::text'))`

Comment: We need more information. Update your question and include the type and str() representation of variables `list` and `li`. And fix your example code. The string is not terminated.

Comment: @meisterluk added and fixed it, Also you don't have to use my same method to extract the data, If you have your own method there is no problem with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It heppened becourse you extract html from 'ul li'. Then you tried to run 'html'.css(). You have to remove ".extract()" where you prepair "list" variable for loop. Like this:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector

with open('input.html') as fd:
    content = fd.read()

response = Selector(text=content)

data = {}
list = response.css('ul li')
for li in list:
    key = li.css('div.LastDiv::text').extract_first()

    if key not in data:
        data[key] = []

    data[key].append(li.css('div > h3::text').extract_first())

print(data)
```

Comment: Got this error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'SelectorList'`

Comment: Thank you a lot for unswer of meisterluk. I fix only error that you provide me. It was better if I run it in my side and fixed future issue too. I edited my code using partially code of meisterluk.

Answer (score 2):

Oleg T.'s answer is incomplete. `data` is a dictionary requiring that keys implement `__hash__` which SelectorList does not. That is why you got this error.

A correct solution is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import collections
from scrapy.selector import Selector

with open('input.html') as fd:
    content = fd.read()

response = Selector(text=content)

data = collections.defaultdict(list)
lst = response.css('ul li') #.extract()
for li in lst:
    key = li.css('div.LastDiv::text')[0].extract()
    data[key].append(li.css('div > h3::text')[0].extract())

print(dict(data))
```

where `input.html` is the file containing the HTML snippet in your question. This prints what your were looking for:

```
{'TheLast': ['TheFirst', 'TheSecond'], 'TheLastNew': ['TheNew']}
```